# fetching multiple rows with same class different result js php

Tags: javascript, php, dom

how can i differentiate multiple rows with same class using javascript? i've searched it but it shows only jquery and i know nothing about it.
my rows always shows the amount in inventory of the last product selected like this example in this pic the example

[image: 1]

here's what i wrote as js function:`

```
function showAmount(variable)
            {
                this.product = variable;
                if(product == '')
                {   
                    document.getElementsByClassName('qte').innerHTML = " ";
                }else
                {
                    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var table = document.getElementById('tbody');
                    //var rows = table.rows.length;
                    //console.log(rows);
                    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('qte');
                    console.log(rows[1]);
                    xmlhttp.onload = function(){
                        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        for(var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++)
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++)
                            {
                                if(product === myObj[i]['NomArt'])
                                {
                                    rows[j].innerHTML = myObj[i]['Qte'];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "templates/Client/products.json", "true");
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
```

`this function add rows to the table`

```
function addItem() {
                items++;
                    // code...
                var html = "<tr>";
                    html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='product[]' list='produit' id='pick' onchange='showAmount(this.value)' ><datalist id='produit'> <?php foreach ($productinfo as $req) { ?><option value='<?php echo $req['NomArt']; ?>'><?php echo $req['NomArt']; } ?></option></datalist></td>";
                    html += "<td  class='text-center qte'></td>";
                    html += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control'  name='qte[]'></td>";
                    html += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='remove(this);'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";
         
                var row = document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow();
                row.innerHTML = html;
            }
```

`
And i couldn't understand others exactly as they showed jquery with Ids and stuff. is there a way to do it with php cuz php approach also gave the same results showing the amount of the last product that's why i took javascript approach but couldn't get a handle of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see your response, but I think the problem is that you're checking one product and updating all rows. You need to identify which row to update, and if your user puts the same product name in two different rows, your system will be confused, so start by changing your function call to onChange="showAmount(this)", so you're passing a DOM element rather than text.

```
function ShowAmount(productInput) {
    
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        row = productInput.parentElement.closest('tr'); // find the table row
        let i = myObj.map(item => item.NomArt).indexOf(productInput.value); // find matching data in response
        row.getElementsByClassName('qte')[0].innerHTML = myQbj[i].Qte // update the row

    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "templates/Client/products.json", "true");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Of course, you're downloading the entire product catalogue every time the user makes a single change. If your database is large, this is very inefficient. You'd be better updating your back end to return data on a specified product.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "templates/Client/products.json?product="+productInput.value, "true");
```

Comment: first, thank you for taking time to answer. now for the code it didn't work although you nailed the point of checking a product and updating all rows it does that, it didnt work for several reasons variable (product) doesn't actually return the value it returns the elements(HTMLCollection) which variabe (i) returns -1 and i added .value to product but returns undefined. and for the point of running function once how do u do that? my function every time u add a row it execute again and again so i dont know the approach of running once. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I missed the onChange=showAmount(this.value). I'll update my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you absolutely very much dude, this stressed my mind for some time and you helped me. Thank you really dude. i have a question what's your sources to learn JS cuz i'll be glad to learn it the way you did and maybe one day i could help others like u helped me. hope life is good to you

Comment: De rien! It's been a while, but I think I learnt from a book. These days, I'd highly recommend freecodecamp. If you usually work on small projects, jquery is much easier than plain js.